# How to determine if a DynamoDB item was indeed deleted?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB provides an API for deleting items. In the returned `DeleteItemOutcome` and `DeleteItemResult` there is no field or method to determine if the key was found and the item was indeed deleted.

The only way to find out if the item was indeed present and deleted, is to request the items' attributes:

`new DeleteItemSpec()
    .withPrimaryKey("key","1")
    .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD))`

This, however, consumes extra read capacity. Is there a more efficient way to check the delete result - key found and deleted / invalid key?

Comment: If you have a key in hand then it presumably came from a DynamoDB item so was, at some point, a valid key. If you really need to know that it still represents a valid item then you can test for that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`DeleteItemResult#getAttributes()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/DeleteItemResult.html#getAttributes--) is *the way* to determine if a `DeleteItem` operation has actually deleted an item, or not.

If you specify `ReturnValue.ALL_OLD` and the item was deleted, a map of item attributes is returned, otherwise and empty map is returned. This is the only way to know for sure if the operation was successful. No other confirmation is returned by the API.

Keep in mind that a `DeleteItem` operation **will consume a minimum of 1 write capacity unit every time**. If the deleted item is larger than 1KB, consumed capacity will be more than 1.

**For reference:** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html#ItemSizeCalculations.Writes

Answer (score 5):

Try using conditional expressions like

```
attribute_exists(my_key)
```

If element doesn't exist conditional check error will be raised

Comment: This is answer is correct, but at least in Node SDK, we use ConditionExpression and not *Conditional* Expression