# When multiple DynamoDB clients delete a specific item, (how) can each client determine if their DeleteItem call was meaningful?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When a DynamoDB client calls DeleteItem on an item, it can use the `ReturnItems` request parameter to be informed of the item's pre-deletion contents in the response: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html#DDB-DeleteItem-request-ReturnValues

When 2 or more clients delete the same item, simultaneously, can they use this parameter to determine which of them *truly* deleted the item, and therefore which clients made a call which wasn't *strictly* necessary? In other words, using this parameter, will exactly-one client see the contents of the item in the DeleteItem response, where all other clients will see a response containing no item contents -- allowing them to correctly deduce that they didn’t materially delete the item?

I believe that it's well-known that, in normal operation, writes to DynamoDB require acknowledgement from 2 of the 3 storage nodes in a partition. I can't find any documentation, formal or otherwise, mentioning equivalent guarantees around deletes; though I can, of course, see why it would be the same.

Given that an update is mentioned as being treated as a delete then a put (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_DynamoDB#Query_execution: "when the log propagator receives an Update operation, it issues both a Delete operation and a Put operation to all indices”), I would happily believe a delete is *literally* treated to the same underlying guarantees as writes.

If a delete **does** require acknowledgement from 2 of the 3 storage nodes then, outside significant system failure scenarios, I think I'm safe to use the `ReturnItems` request parameter to determine which client actually managed to delete an item. Is there anything which invalidates this assumption, in either normal operation or overloaded-and-slow-but-not-failed storage node operation? I’m explicitly not thinking about “DynamoDB is down in $REGION” mode, for the sake of argument ...

[My use case is for this to act as a coordination mechanism for which client should work on the specific item just deleted; hence I don't believe there are any issues around inconsistent-read-after-delete, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the underlying mechanism is similar to yours, it should work.
If you're interested in how this works under the hood, I recommend watching this [great re:invent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ) by Rick Houlihan. He is a more authoritative voice on this.

Although it should work that way, I would still go a route that makes what's going on more explicit to the reader/developer. I've used something like this in the past. I'm making a conditional delete on the item with the condition being that the item exists. I'll get an exception that the item doesn't exist and can handle that.

```py
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions

from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key

# Create table resource etc.

try:
    response = table_resource.delete_item(
        Key={
            "key": item["key"]
        },
        ConditionExpression=Key("key").eq(item["key"])
    )
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ConditionalCheckFailedException':
        # This is fine, it just means the object doesn't didn't exist.
        # It means either another writer was faster or there was no such item in the first place.
        pass
    else:
        LOGGER.error(e)
        raise e
```

Another solution (for java) is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46464303/how-to-determine-if-a-dynamodb-item-was-indeed-deleted).

Comment: Thank you for those pointers; it was exactly that talk (and Rick's *amazingly* densely-packed 2018 talk!) that prompted me to wonder about the low-level behaviours, and which of them I could rely on :-)

Comment: Yeah, that guy is just amazing, I have the 2020 version of the dynamodb design patterns on my todo list :D